# How does printf take endianness into account behind the scenes?

Tags: c, endianness, glibc

`prtinf` uses the `write` system call behind the scenes which calls `vfprintf_internal` defined in `glibc` defined here:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c.html

I'm suspecting down the line it puts the characters one by one in some VGA buffer like `0xB8000` as explained here:

https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones

My question is:

- Does it automatically take care of the machine endianness?

If data is stored in reverse in memory in LE machines, it should first reverse them back before printing them byte by byte correct?
Where does that happen? Maybe `itoa` is doing that while converting each `int` to a `char`?

Comment: Are you using Unicode?  Because if this is ASCII, *there is no endianness.* A byte is a byte.

Comment: `puts the characters one by one in some VGA buffer like 0xB8000 as` There are way many layers. No, `glibc` calls `write()` system call and execution travels to kernel. User space programs cannot (with ease) access VGA buffers.. `putchar system call` there is no "puchar" system call. [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: And [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/fileops.c.html#1185) inside `FILE*` vtable is the call to `write` system call (`__write` is defined [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c.html#__write)).

Comment: @RobertHarvey if I do `printf("%d\n", 5);`, this is not a byte, it's 4 bytes.

Comment: @KamilCuk corrected.

Comment: I would imagine that C hands your `5` to the `printf` function  as an `int`, exactly as you would expect.  At that level, you're not thinking about endianness at all.

Comment: The conversion between a number to ascii characters doesn't need to be endianess aware. It's just math. Get rest of division per 10. Add that to `'0'`. Print result. Divide by 10. Etc. You don't need to know implementation details for doing math. The job is done in [_itoa_work](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c.html#652)  defined [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/_itoa.c.html#_itoa_word). In detail you specifically design the algorithms to not depent on endianess, so they will work on different machines.